# Combine like lines based off of date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'm having trouble finishing this query. The end result I'm looking for is:
[image: desired result]

I have so far wrote this query:

```
SELECT
to_char(favi.date::date, 'mm-dd-yyyy') AS "Date",
(SELECT COUNT(dv.severity) WHERE dv.severity='Critical') AS "Critical Vulns",
(SELECT COUNT(dv.severity) WHERE dv.severity='Severe') AS "Severe Vulns",
(SELECT COUNT(dv.severity) WHERE dv.severity='Moderate') AS "Moderate Vulns",
COUNT(favi.asset_id) AS "Asset Count"
FROM fact_asset_vulnerability_instance favi
JOIN dim_vulnerability dv ON dv.vulnerability_id=favi.vulnerability_id
GROUP BY to_char(favi.date::date, 'mm-dd-yyyy'), dv.severity
ORDER BY to_char(favi.date::date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

My results though are:

[image: current outcome]

How exactly do I combine the rows on the date? The results split the date into three rows each one displaying the actual count for whatever severity it is. I just want one row per date that shows each of the severity values on one line.

I've played around with UNION, DISTINCT, FULL JOIN, etc but this is slightly past my knowledge of how to get the desired results.

Comment: 1) You do not need to do  `GROUP BY to_char(favi.date::date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')` just do `GROUP BY favi_date`. Same for the `ORDER BY`. Postgres does not need a formatted date string to properly group, order. 2) Eliminate the `, dv.severity` in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Tip:  Whenever possible, always post text - *as text*.  Posting a screen shot of  data samples, code, etc.. just limits the amount of help you'll receive, because we can't copy text from an image (or put together queries from it). So you're left hoping someone spots the problem visually, or feels like re-typing all of the data.  Please see [mre].

Comment: I don't use postgresql, but a common approach is using a conditional SUM() like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e690fb90fa54d1fe97c1ab46cb76001c .  Note, using a single table because I don't have time to retype the sample data rn, but the concept is the same.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it wouldn't let me drop the dv.severity GROUP BY unfortunately due to the way I was trying to query the severity columns.

Comment: @SOS I thought by providing the SQL query as code it let you copy and paste so I don't know what I'm missing there but you were right with the SUM() function. See solution below.

Comment: @Happy.Hartman - It does let you copy the query, but without any sample data to go with it, it takes more time to suggest a solution because we have to create the tables and load sample data from scratch :) Fortunately this was a simpler query, but it always speeds things up if a full example (with CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements) is provided, i.e. Similar to the earlier fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e690fb90fa54d1fe97c1ab46cb76001c

Comment: ... that way we can actually run the query in our own environment and provide you with something we've already tested, rather than just psuedo code or guesses.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is what ended up working.

```
SELECT
to_char(favi.date::date, 'mm-dd-yyyy') AS "Date",
SUM(CASE WHEN dv.severity = 'Critical' THEN 1 END) AS "Critical Vulns",
SUM(CASE WHEN dv.severity = 'Severe' THEN 1 END) AS "Severe Vulns",
SUM(CASE WHEN dv.severity = 'Moderate' THEN 1 END) AS "Moderate Vulns",
COUNT(favi.asset_id) AS "Asset Count"
FROM fact_asset_vulnerability_instance favi
JOIN dim_vulnerability dv ON dv.vulnerability_id=favi.vulnerability_id
GROUP BY to_char(favi.date::date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
ORDER BY to_char(favi.date::date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

so by doing the SUM function as @SOS mentioned I was able to drop the GROUP BY on dv.severity

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working! Thanks for posting the final code for the next person with the same issue.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to get away from the habitat of  this: `to_char(favi.date::date, 'mm-dd-yyyy')`. That groups/orders by a string which is not really what you want, for two reasons there is the added overhead of the cast and depending on the string template it may not work the way you want. If `favi.date` is actually stored as a `date` type then just use it unmodified.